# Tab separated files with datatool package?

Tags: datatool

The documentation of the package `datatool` says that the `\DTLsettabseparator` command changes the separator in `.csv`-Files from the default comma to the tab character. **What it really does for me is change it to space. Tabs are simply ignored by datatool.** Datatool requires space as separator even with the tabseparator command. **Is there a way to change it to tabs for real?**

Also is there a way to tell `datatool` to **ignore multiple, consecutive separators** (i.e. multiple tab characters in a row)? When I write "1,,,3" in my `.csv` file (for readability comma being the separator here instead of the desired tab), I don't mean datatool to think the "1" is in the first column and the "3" in the fourth. That should be just do columns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this problem with `datatool` not recognising tabs. I believe there is a bug in the definition of `\DTLsettabseparator` in `datatool.sty`. 
`\DTLsettabseparator` tries to make `\DTLsetseparator` a tab but fails, but you can override this by making `\DTLsetseparator` a tab in your document using:

```
\catcode`\^^I=12 %
\DTLsetseparator{   }%
```

The gap in `{ }` is a tab.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I did use the 4 space trick for code but for some reason it failed, along with newline.

Comment: I've checked with Nicola Talbot: this should be working in the upcoming v2.04.

Answer (score 1):

For XeLaTeX this works without **^^I**:

```
\catcode`\ 12%
\DTLsetseparator{   }%
```

The same as above the gap in { } is a tab.